# Regex to extract first part of string in Apache Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I need to extract post code district from the input data below

```
AB55 4
DD7 6LL
DD5 2HI
```

My Code

```
A = load 'data' as postcode:chararray;
B = foreach A {
code_district = REGEX_EXTRACT(postcode,'<SOME EXP>',1);
generate code_district;
};
dump B;
```

Output should look like

```
AB55
DD7
DD5
```

what should be the regular expression to extract the first part of the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the below Regex?

**Option1:**

```
A = LOAD 'input' as postcode:chararray;
code_district = FOREACH A GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT(postcode,'(\\w+).*',1);
DUMP code_district;
```

**Option2:**

```
A = LOAD 'input' as postcode:chararray;
code_district = FOREACH A GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT(postcode,'([a-zA-Z0-9]+).*',1);
DUMP code_district;
```

**Output:**

```
(AB55)
(DD7)
(DD5)
```

Comment: This does not work with NON-ASCII chararrays.i.e. ISO-8859-9